# How to replace empty string with \N in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to replace empty string with `\N` in spark `dataframe`.

I tried the below one:

```
Df.na.replace(Seq("column1"),Map("" -> null)).na.fill("\N", Seq("column1"))
```

It's throwing me an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do like below

```
//Input df

+-----+-------+
| name|address|
+-----+-------+
|Manoj|Chennai|
|     |  Delhi|
|Alice|       |
+-----+-------+

//Replacement logic

df.na.replace(Seq("name","address"),Map(""->"\\n")).show

//Output df
+-----+-------+
| name|address|
+-----+-------+
|Manoj|Chennai|
|   \n|  Delhi|
|Alice|     \n|
+-----+-------+
```